# Javascript - catch name in variable string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to catch a person's name. The name would be entered in a text box such as:

my name is Robert or yes my name is Robert etc.

I don't know where the actual name will fall however because of intro words etc.

I was thinking something like this.

1. I search for "my name is"
2. I capture it in an array
3. I split the array
4. I now know the actual name follows as such:

> `namesParts[0]` - would be "my"
>
> `namesParts[1]` - would be "name"
>
> `namesParts[2]` - would be "is"
>
> `namesParts[3]` - would be the name i'm looking for.

Something perhaps like the below but this doesn't work.

```
if (input.search("my name is")!= -1) {
    var names = input.match(/my name is/);
    var namesParts = names.split(' '); 
    var one = namesParts[3];
    document.result.result.value = "Ok your name is "+one+".";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: will the intro words always be the same?

Comment: "Robert is my name." "I'm known as Robert." "Call me Bruce." "Robert Peters."

Comment: @nnnnnn: Call me may be

Comment: @zerkms - Call me anything, as long as you call me.

Comment: @zerkms Hey! I just met you!

Comment: @alex: you know where to find me - in every single js-related question )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all other words will start with lower case letter you could use

```
'my name is Robert'.match(/[A-Z]+\w*/);
```

otherwise

```
'My name is Robert'.match(/my name is (\S+)/i);
```

Comment: ok once I got the match then something like this:                                                                                                                                    var names = names[1];

Comment: @mister movie: I'm still not sure what you're talking about

Comment: I was trying to fit your example into my original "if statement" presented above. I think I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the JavaScript `String.split` Method.

Examples:

```
var str="my name is Robert";
var n=str.split('my name is ');
alert('1. Length: '+n.length +' Array: '+ n);

var str="my name is Robert";
var n=str.split(' ');
alert('2. Length: '+n.length +' Array: '+ n);

var str="my name is Robert";
var n=str.split('');
alert('3. Length: '+n.length +' Array: '+ n);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/a4D8q/